# Call a function from another function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button click event which insert comment text from textbox to database.Now i need to call a function that displays comment after the click event of insert comment button is clicked.Here's the code.

With this code I insert text to database

```
 protected void cmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //DateTime.Now.ToString();
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    DataListItem dli = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    TextBox tx = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("tb_cmt");
    Label lb = (Label)dli.FindControl("lbl_sid");
    string userid = Session["userid"].ToString();

    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into comment(ecomment,sid,my_date,reg_id) values(@myecomment,@mysid,@mydate,@reg_id)", sq.con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myecomment", tx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mysid", lb.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mydate", DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm, MMM  dd, yyyy"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_id", userid);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sq.con.Dispose();
    sq.con.Close();
    tx.Text = "";

    //bind_dlcmt( 1 );

}
```

Now here's the code to display comment from database.

```
 public void showdata()
{
    string str = gstr;
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sub_catTbl where sid='" + str + "' ", sq.con);
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sub_catTbl", sq.con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    mydatalist.DataSource = dt;
    mydatalist.DataBind();
    sq.con.Dispose();
    sq.con.Close();


    foreach (DataListItem dli in mydatalist.Items)
    {
        bind_dlcmt(dli.ItemIndex);
        //blin_dlcmt();

    }
}

 public void bind_dlcmt(int itm_indx)
{
    string str = gstr;
    //int sid = Convert.ToInt32(mydatalist.DataKeys[itm_indx]);
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 4 * from comment where sid='" + str + "' order by my_date desc", sq.con);
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where sid=@sid ", sq.con);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    DataList dl = (DataList)mydatalist.Items[itm_indx].FindControl("dl_cmt");
    dl.DataSource = sdr;
    dl.DataBind();
}
```

I need to call the function `binddlcmt()` in the last line of the `cmt_Click` button click event.With the one argument inside the function, i am not sure how do i call the function.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know how to get the item-index in the button-click event handler?

Use [`DataListItem.ItemIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalistitem.itemindex(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
protected void cmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    DataListItem dli = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    // ...
    bind_dlcmt( dli.ItemIndex );
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better MVC to inform the Controller of a datachange which in turn triggers a GUI-Update?

Comment: Why do you think that OP is using MVCV? This is plain ASP.NET and OP is trying to pass the index of a `DataListView`'s `DataListItem` to another method on server.

Comment: Now, that you say it... ok, forget my comment.

Comment: @TimSchmelter when i call the `bind_dlcmt()`,it is supposed to display data with updated data just inserted but..when i click the button nothing is displayed.

Comment: @sum1: i'm afraid that i don't understand the the problem. Maybe you should clarify your question so that other people can help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry for that...as you can see the function `bind_dlcmt()` is ment to show data.Its called in Page_load so at first the data is displayed.But when the `bind_dlcmt` is called from button click event `cmt_click`..it no more displays data.Why?